# How to open a jQuery-UI-Accordion section from same accordion or page?

Tags: hyperlink, skip, jquery-ui-accordion

This is what I've got yet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: false,
            autoHeight: false,<br/>
            navigation: true,
            header: 'p.menuitem'
        });
        $("p.menuitem a").click(function(event){
            window.location.hash=this.hash;
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="accordion">
    <div>
        <p class="menuitem" id="item1"><a href="#item1">Section1</a></p>
        <div>Phasellus mattis <a href="#item2">tincidunt</a> nibh.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="menuitem" id="item2"><a href="#item2">Section2</a></p>
        <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="menuitem" id="item3"><a href="#item3">Section3</a></p>
        <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you surely've already noticed, there's a skip link in Section1 of the accordion.
The problems to be solved are:

1. The mentioned skip link prevents the accordion section 2 from opening when calling the tis page by

   ```
   http://www.domain.tld/index.htm#item2
   ```

   while the other ones,

   ```
   http://www.domain.tld/index.htm#item1
   ```

   or

   ```
   http://www.domain.tld/index.htm#item3
   ```

   are still working well.
2. Clicking the skip link won't open the section 2 of the accordion.
   Is there any chance to get tese things working? I've searched a lot, but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Both problems are solved!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: false,
            autoHeight: false,
            navigation: true,
            header: 'p.menuitem'
        });

        $("p.menuitem a").click(function(event){
            window.location.hash=this.hash;
        });

        if($(location).attr("hash")) $("a[hash="+$(location).attr("hash")+"]").click();
    });

    function openpanel(section) {   
        $("#accordion").accordion("activate", section);
    }
</script>

<div id="accordion">
    <div>
        <p class="menuitem" id="item1"><a href="#item1">Section1</a></p>
        <div>Phasellus mattis <a href="#item2" onclick="javascript:openpanel(1)">tincidunt</a> nibh.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="menuitem" id="item2"><a href="#item2">Section2</a></p>
        <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="menuitem" id="item3"><a href="#item3">Section3</a></p>
        <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
    </div>
</div
```